# Used 4 primary partitions, now need to add more space

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos

I currently have CentOS 6.5 running on a VM in a live environment. The need to increase space has arrisen several times, and after following guides online it has worked successfully until today.

Previously I have created primary paritions and now have 4 which I understand is the maximum.

`fdisk -l` shows the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002d169

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        2611    20458496   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3            6528        8485    15727635   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda4            2611        6527    31456607+  8e  Linux LVM

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_kaylavm-lv_root: 65.1 GB, 65062043648 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7910 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_kaylavm-lv_swap: 4194 MB, 4194304000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 509 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

What is the correct way without losing data to remove /dev/sda4 and create an extended partition (assuming that is the correct way to do things)?

Looking online I can see many guides on how to extend, but none relating to the above.

**Update**

`pvs` shows:

```
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg_kaylavm lvm2 a--  19.51g    0
  /dev/sda3  vg_kaylavm lvm2 a--  15.00g    0
  /dev/sda4  vg_kaylavm lvm2 a--  30.00g    0
```

`lvs` shows:

```
  LV      VG        Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_root vg_kaylavm -wi-ao---- 60.59g
  lv_swap vg_kaylavm -wi-ao----  3.91g
```

Comment: How much of the 107.4GB disk space is used up?

Comment: The output of `pvs`, and `lvs` would have been helpful, but is fine as is.  Also you should add a `-u` to your fdisk command, your partitions are not cylinder aligned.  ie `fdisk -l -u`.

Comment: @Zoredache I've added the lvs and pvs outputs above for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Just change sda3 to have a ending point that new end of the drive after resizing the virtual disk.  After you have changed the partition size, then just run `pvresize`.

For the record you should have done that in the first place instead of creating the additional PVs.

Another option would have been to simply add another virtual disk.  Which should be easy depending on your hypervisor.  Once adding a new virtual disk, add it as another physical volume.

Comment: Adding a virtual disk is an option, however I'd rather just extend the current drive space I have. Is there a way to fix the current partition setup without losing data (i.e. expanding /dev/sda1/ to have all space)?

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd create new let's say 1000GB drive in one slice
2. boot any live distro you are familiar with
3. dd boot record, first (boot partition) and second (sda2) partition from old drive image to new drive image
4. resize second partition on new drive image to fill disc
5. resize filesystem on data partition on new disc to cover all free space
6. mount third data partition from first drive (sda3) and copy all data to new data partition on new drive
7. mount fourth data partition from first drive (sda4) and copy all data to new data partition on new drive
8. boot machine from new 1000GB drive
9. enjoy!